# How to create a series of cross sections in arcgis 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, dem

My ouput should be a series of cross-sections (10 meters apart) along a center line of a river. The input data is a raster data set with elevation values. Can I also automatically generate the lines where my cross sections should be which is at 10-meter regular interval and along a specific line?

Comment: What do you mean by cross section- just a perpendicular with defined length at specific gap?

Answer (score 1):

There is an ArcGIS Add-In, CHaMP Topo Toolbar, that can calculate a series of cross sections both wetted and bankfull. The Add-In is available for download as well as documentation/tutorials from [this webpage](http://champtools.northarrowresearch.com/).

It is a fairly complex computation to calculate cross-sections from a DEM. This toolbar splits the operation up into many separate tools such as calculating wetted and bankfull extent from the raw surveyed data, calculating centerlines (wetted/bankfull) of which the cross section would be based from, and other hydro/topo parameters associated with channel dynamics. Given the complexity of these calculations this toolbar is designed to work with data collected with a specific protocol, CHaMP, specifics of which [can be found here](https://www.champmonitoring.org/Program/Details/1#tab-protocol~#protocol2038).

However outside of following the data protocol and workflow of this AddIn I am not aware of a ArcGIS tool that uses a centerline and a DEM only as input to calculate cross sections.

Comment: Good tool indeed! Needs have alook.